# What is __ext_vector_type__ and simd?

Tags: c++, c, reference, clang, simd

I'm playing with Apple Metal API along with so called *simd* library. There's such code in a header:

```
typedef __attribute__((__ext_vector_type__(3))) float vector_float3;
```

And I'm curious what it actually does and why the compiler doesn't allow references to **vector_float3** in a function's argument or in the next manner:

```
vector_float3  v;
vector_float3& ref = v;
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It appears to be a clang extension to [GNU C vector extensions](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Vector-Extensions.html), where something like this would be normal:

```
typedef int v4si __attribute__ ((vector_size (16)));
```

---

Googling for `ext_vector_type` without the leading/trailing underscores found [the Clang docs](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/LanguageExtensions.html#vectors-and-extended-vectors).  (The underscores version is usable in headers even if some program had used `#define` on the non-underscores version of the token.  But names with leading underscores in the global namespace are reserved for the implementation.)

My best guess is that it's **a way to let the compiler know you only care about the value of the first 3 elements of a 4 element SIMD register.**  So it can potentially do optimizations that leave different garbage in the high element than the source would have.

---

> why the compiler doesn't allow references to `vector_float3`

Works for me with clang3.8.  Try a different compiler.

```
typedef __attribute__((__ext_vector_type__(3))) float vector_float3;

int foo(vector_float3 &arg) {
  vector_float3  v;
  vector_float3& ref = v;  // unused, but syntactically valid
  return arg[0];           // return the low element of the vector, converted to an integer.  GNU C vector-extensions syntax.
}
```

[compiles to the following asm on the Godbolt compiler explorer](http://gcc.godbolt.org/#compilers:!((compiler:clang380,options:%27-std%3Dgnu%2B%2B11+-Wall+-Wextra+-O3+-fno-verbose-asm+-march%3Dnehalem%27,source:%27typedef+__attribute__((__ext_vector_type__(3)))+float+vector_float3%3B%0A%0Aint+foo(vector_float3+%26arg)+%7B%0A++vector_float3++v%3B%0A++vector_float3%26+ref+%3D+v%3B%0A++return+arg%5B0%5D%3B%0A%7D%0A%27)),filterAsm:(commentOnly:!t,directives:!t,intel:!t,labels:!t),version:3)

```
    # targeting x86-64 SystemV ABI (so the first integer/pointer arg is in rdi)
    cvttss2si       eax, dword ptr [rdi]
    ret
```